# DropDownList doesn't change it's value

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is so flexible, so I dont know what is the right title for this question. I'll try to describe my problem clearly, hope you can understand, if you dont, please ask.

I use a DropDownList in my notice.aspx page.

```
DropDownlist value: 1--> show notice in one day ago; 2--> 7 days ago;3--> 30 days ago.
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTime" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexNotice_Changed"
            AutoPostBack="true" >
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1 day ago  </asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="2"> 7 days ago </asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="3"> 30 days ago </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

And code in notice.aspx.cs

```
   private static string key;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();

            }              
        }

            public void BindData()
            {
             string sql="";
                  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListTime.SelectedValue))
                  {
                      key = "3";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      key = DropDownListTime.SelectedValue.ToString();
                  }
                  if(key.Equals("1"))
                 {
                      sql="select top 5 notice in 1 day ago...";//show 
                  }
                 if(key.Equals("2"))
                {
                     sql="select top 5 notice in 7 day ago...";
                 }
               if(key.Equals("3"))
                {
                       sql="select top 5 notice in 30 day ago...";
                }
                  Datatable dt= excute(sql);
                    ...
               HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("Allnotice.aspx?key={0}",key);// go to page to show all notices with `1 day`,`7days`,`30 days` ago depend on the `key`
        }
 public  void IndexNotice_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }
```

When I click on the Hyperlink1, the key alway is 3; so the Allnotice.aspx page is alway show the notices in 30days ago.

I really dont know why the value of dropdownlist is always 3. 
Is there any mistake in my code above, please help!!!

UPDATE:

I've deleted the line:  `private static string key;` and declare `string key=""` in `BindData()` it still works wrong.

It seems there is no problem with `DropDownListTime.SelectedValue`. When I debug, I saw the variable key is right (I mean it is right with the time I choosed). But when I click on the Hyperlink, the addressbar is show the `key=3`.

Help!!!

Comment: Are you using the DropDownList to configure where the HyperLink goes, or to display data, or both?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and dont see any mistake, always the Key change If I click other option

Comment: @Freak_Droid yes, me too, the key change when I click other option, but when I choose one option, then click the HyperLink-> the new page open with the value key =3

Comment: @GarrisonNeely no, I just use the HyperLink to Nagative and pass the value key to allnotice.aspx page

Answer (score 1):

On initial page load, the key will always be 3. As the result, hyperlink's key is 3.

Once you select a new value in DropDownList, the hyperlink's key will change to whatever value you selected.

**What I notice is you should not use static value in your scenario.**

```
private static string key;
```

Delete above line, and move it inside `BindData()` method

```
public void BindData()
{
    string key;
    string sql = "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListTime.SelectedValue))
    {
        key = "3";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: let's me try and I'll give you the result soon

Comment: Set a break point at `public void IndexNotice_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {`. If break point hit, then step throw (F10) until `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListTime.SelectedValue))`. Tell me the value of `DropDownListTime.SelectedValue`

Comment: It seems there is no problem with DropDownListTime.SelectedValue. When I debug, I saw the variable key is right (I mean it is right with the time I choosed). But when I click on the Hyperlink, the addressbar is show the key=3.

Comment: Please upload the HTML source (of the browser) before selecting  and after selecting dropdownlist.

Answer (score -1):

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if(Request.QueryString["key"]!=null)
            {
                 DropDownListTime.SelectedValue= QueryString["key"];
            }

            BindData();

        }              
    }
```