# DropDownList doesn't change it's value when Navigate to other page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dropdownlist in my aspx page, with value:

```
//DropDownlist value: 1--> show notice in one day ago; 2--> 7 days ago;3--> 30 days ago.

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTime" runat="server">
                    AutoPostBack="true" >
   <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1 day ago  </asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2"> 7 days ago </asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3"> 30 days ago </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And code in cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         BindData();
     }              
}

public void BindData()
{
   string key="";
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownListTime.SelectedValue))
   {
       key = "3";
   }
   else
   {
       key = DropDownListTime.SelectedValue.ToString();
   }

   HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("Allnotice.aspx?key={0}",key);
  // go to page to show all notices with `1 day`,`7days`,`30 days` ago depend on the `key`
}

public  void IndexNotice_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BindData();
}
```

When debugging, the key is right with the option I choose. But After choose an option in Dropdownlist, I click in the Hyperlink, it pass to `Allnotice.aspx` page with key="3". Always and always even what option I chose.

For detail: I choose `7 days ago`---> debug: `key= 2`--> then click on Hyperlink---> the next page recieved the `key=3`.

Help!!!!

UPDATE: I've asked this problem but no one can help. So I try to describe it in a simple way, hope you dont mind if it's duplicate.

[DropDownList doesn't change it's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188773/dropdownlist-doesnt-change-its-value/19189028#19189028)

Comment: I have formatted your code for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned an event handler to DropdownList control, so even though page is posting back it won't fire `IndexNotice_Changed` event as you are expecting.

```
//Assign IndexNotice_Changed event to the OnSelectedIndexChanged 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTime" 
                  Runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexNotice_Changed" > //NOTE HERE
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1 day ago  </asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2"> 7 days ago </asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3"> 30 days ago </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Yes, it has OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexNotice_Changed" in my code, I forgot it when copy

Comment: When I degug, the key is right (I means it is right with each option chosen). then when I click on the hyperlink, the addressbar show : key=3 always

Comment: It seems there no problem with Dropdownlist, it give back the right value of key. I just wonder if when the page load again after I chose Dropdownlist, the key has change to defautl??

Comment: Do you wan't open up a new window for the new link?

Comment: exactly it has a Repeater.binddata() in BindData() function. When I choose an option-> key="1" (for example)-> select the news in 1 days ago-> bind data to the Repeater + the key will be passed by the Hyperlink. So BindData() has 2 tasks: Bind repeater data + Hyperlink.Navigate to orther page.

Comment: It is difficult to get the whole picture of what is happening without looking at the rest of the code. Glad you have found the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

one option could be using a hiddenfield value in javascript to save always the selected option

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#<%=DropDownListTime.ClientID%>").change(function(e) {
    var dpdVal=$("#<%=DropDownListTime.ClientID%>").val();
    document.getElementById("<%=hiddenFieldControl.ClientID%>").value=dpdVal;
 });
</script>
```

so, you can replace for this:

```
public void BindData()
{
   string key="";
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hiddenFieldControl.Value))
   {
       key = "3";
   }
   else
   {
       key = hiddenFieldControl.Value.ToString();
   }

   HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("Allnotice.aspx?key={0}",key);
  // go to page to show all notices with `1 day`,`7days`,`30 days` ago depend on the `key`
}
```

Comment: What is exactly hiddenFieldControl? Can you tell me more?

Comment: a hiddenFieldControl is a server control where you can store information in the asp page, i use it when i have troubles to maintain values in server side or when i have to pass values from client side to server side, so i store the value using javascript, and can get value from server side.
<asp:HiddenField  id="hdnFieldControl" runat="server"/>